# ASP Treeview link to file not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

For a ASP Page, i created a Treeview that lists all the Subfolders and PDFs in a RootFolder.
I want the PDFs to be opened on a click.

Code

```
<asp:TreeView ID="QMTreeView" runat="server" Width="650px" NodeIndent="30" ShowLines="False" PopulateNodesFromClient="False">
    <LeafNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/Bilder/Icons/Document-icon.png" />
    <NodeStyle ImageUrl="~/Bilder/Icons/Folder-icon.png" />
    <RootNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/Bilder/Icons/Lamp-icon.png" />
</asp:TreeView>
```

Code

```
private void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
    {
        treeView.Nodes.Clear();
        var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        treeView.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo));
    }

    private static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {
        var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);

        foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            directoryNode.ChildNodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
        }

        foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
        {
//here Comes the problematic line
            TreeNode temp = new TreeNode(file.FullName,file.FullName,null,file.FullName,"_blank");
            directoryNode.ChildNodes.Add(temp);
        }

        return directoryNode;
    }
```

if i click on the pdf node (Displays a link in the status bar) nothing happens...

if i Change this line

```
TreeNode temp = new TreeNode(file.FullName,file.FullName,null,file.FullName,"_blank");
```

to

```
TreeNode temp = new TreeNode(file.Name, file.DirectoryName + "/" + file.Name, null, file.DirectoryName + "/" + file.Name, "_blank");
```

the link is correct (sans triple / (?) ) but it wont open the file.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: I tried to access a local file from a webserver, that isn't allowed by Windows.
As soon as i changed the path variable to somewhere on the Server it works.

Also, the treenode works as suggested by nuclear-sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TreeNode temp = new TreeNode(file.FullName,file.FullName, file.DirectoryName + @"\" + file.FullName);
```

Comment: no difference, still shows three / and doesn't open the files

Comment: i postpone the use of listview for the moment, i'll build the tree programmatically.